# Database hierarchy table names... I've been asked to rename tables twice now

Tags: database

I have a table called `Category`. It has a one-to-many relationship with another table called `Subject`. And that has the same relationship to another table called `Course`. And same to `Lesson`. All of these have a one-to-many relationship to the next table mentioned.

So a `Category` has many `Subject`s which has many `Course`s which has many `Lesson`s. My database is actually more complicated than that, but I'm keeping it simple in this question.

I've recently been asked to rename the `Subject` table to `Course`, and the `Course` table to `Topic`. This is the second time I've been asked to do so and this causes a huge re-write of much of the code.

So an idea came up in our meeting, which is to just call the tables `FirstTable`, `SecondTable`, etc. But this causes two problems. The first is that it would be confusing to know which table represents which model name, and the second is that if in the future, we add a table in-between, we would have to call it something like `TableOnePointFive` if it goes in between the first and second table.

Another idea was to make our own names and allow have another table to store their names. But this would cause confusion as the developers would have to look up which table represents which model name.

Is there any way to get around this?

Comment: How extensive is the re-write?  At the very least, the product owner(s) should be made aware of the cost of business decisions.

Comment: @David it's a project I was assigned to at work. The project is already about a year in. So there's lots of code. We also plan to add more developers in the future instead of just me.